# iOS having issues with UITableView programmatically selecting multiple cells and displaying a check

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, multi-select

I have an app that the user can select multiple items on a `UITableView`. They then hit an add button and it updates the array. It then rewinds back to the previous VC. Now when the user clicks to go back to update the selections.

I want the cell to be selected and the `accessoryStyle` to be checked. So far everything works except selecting the cell. So the array will have several options and those selected options have the checkmark.

When the user selects a cell the `didSelect` is supposed to add that option to the array if it isn't already. When the user de-selects the cell `didDeselect` is called and the item is removed from the array. (Also the checkmark either is displayed or not).

Now the problem is when the user goes back in the cells that have check marks aren't selected and when they select that sell it calls `didSelect` instead of `didDeselect`. Most of the tutorials and help I have found seem to work only for single select and I can't seem to get the cell to highlight. See images for a bit more clarification.

**NEW ISSUE / UPDATE**

Well the initial problem is fixed. Now when I select element 0 of the array the 10 element of the array has the accessory changed as well. This also repeats progressively.

this is my array setup

```swift
let expansionBayList: [ExpansionBay] = [ArcaneLaboratory(), CargoHold(), EscapePods(), GuestQuarters(), HangarBay(),
                            LifeBoats(), MedicalBay(), PassengerSeating(), PowerCoreHousing(), RecreationSuiteGym(),
                            RecreationSuiteTrividDen(), RecreationSuiteHAC(), ScienceLab(), SealedEnviromentChamber(), ShuttleBay()]
```

So when I select Arcane Laboratory from the list, Recreation Suite Trivid Den also has a check mark but is not selected. I am assuming this has something do with the reuseIdentifier? I am assuming I need that to be cleared when I scrolled?

I tried the following (I tired it in cellForRowAt):

```swift
cell.isSelected = true
cell.isHighlighted = true
```

Also I tried the following (in viewDidLoad):

```
multiSelectTbl.allowsMultipleSelection = true
multiSelectTbl.allowsSelectionDuringEditing = true
```

This is the first time the user updates this screen.

[image]

This is what happens when the user selects Expansion Bay on the previous screen to update and make changes. How do I get it so that each cell that has a checkmark is also highlighted like in the first image?

There is an array that determines what boxes should have the checkmark.

[image]

Comment: Add the `isSelected` information to the data model and set `isSelected` and the `accessoryView` of the cell in `cellForRow`. In `didSelectRow/didDeselectRow` update the model and reload the row.

Comment: I am a bit lost on what you suggested. How will updating didSelectRow/didDeselectRow help my situation when the VC loads?

Comment: `didSelectRow/didDeselectRow` don't matter. It helps your situation because the table view is reloaded when the VC loads and your cells will be correctly displayed in `cellForRow`.

Comment: Now I am not sure what you mean by add `isSelected` in the data model. And when you mean reload the data do a `tableview.reload()`

Comment: No, in `didSelectRow/didDeselectRow` the `indexPath` is passed. Reload only this particular row with `reloadRows(at:with:)`.

Comment: I apologize I am still learning. I appreciate the help so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override the `setSelected` method in the custom tableview cell class,

and use `tableview.selectRow(at:)` function to select cells.

Use `tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows` to get selected indexPaths in the table.

Here is a good implementation.
https://github.com/yonat/SelectionList

**Reply To New Issue:** 
Please follow the steps.

1. `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear` method

   ```
       var itemsToBeSelected: [String]?
       var listItems: [String]? 

       ....
       override func viewDidLoad() {
           super.viewDidLoad()
           if let selected = self.itemsToBeSelected, let listItems = self.listItems {
               selected.forEach { (item) in
               if let index = listItems.index(of: item) {
                   let indexPath = IndexPath(item: index, section: 0)
                   self.tableView.selectRow(at: indexPath, animated: false, scrollPosition: .none)
               }
           }
       }
   ```

   `self.itemsToBeSelected` means they need to be selected by default in the list when the view controller appears. it's just an array of `String` in the above example.
2. `cellForRowAt` method

   > No need to call `cell.isSelected = true/false` or `cell.isHighlighted = true/false`

   if the cell is a custom cell, you can just apply the content to the cell only. and in the custom cell class, just override setSelected method.

   ```
   class ExpansionBayCell {
       ....
       override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
           super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
           self.checkBox.isChecked = self.isSelected
       }
   }
   ```
3. when it's time to get all selected values and close the view controller

   ```
   func btnDonePressed() {        
       guard let indexPaths = tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows else {
           btnBackPressed()            
           return
       }

       let items = indexPaths.map { self.listItems[$0.row] }
       completion(items)
       btnBackPressed()
   }
   ```

Comment: I thought it did. It brought a new issue. I updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

To set initial selected state for rows you should use 
`tableView.selectRow(at: indexPath, animated: false, scrollPosition: .none)`

I don't know how expactly UITableView selection works, but it seems like isSelected flag on UITableViewCell is just for rendering
So if you set isSelected on cell the tableView doesn't it has been selected and calls didSelect instead of didDeselect

Answer (score 0):

In this case first, you need to add support for the multiple selections in order to do it first set the `allowsMultipleSelection` and `allowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing` to true.

**For Example:-**

```
self.tableView.allowsMultipleSelection = true
self.tableView.allowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing = true
```

Then create a `CustomTableViewCell` which will subclass a `UITableViewCell`.
Override the `setSelected` method.

**For example:-**

```
class CustomTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        self.selectionStyle = .none
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
        self.accessoryType = selected ? .checkmark : .none
    }
}
```

Now you can use your custom cell in the `cellForRow` method:

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", 
    for: indexPath) as? CustomTableViewCell
cell.setSelected(isSelected, animated: true)
```